# Deploy changes to Docker container using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration

Docker newbie here.

I have set up and docker container to run a simple Node JS application.

Let's say I am having a new version of my application (e.g **1.1**) which has to be deployed by a Jenkins CI.  Here I am getting a bit lost about what exactly the Jenkins CI should do:

- Should shut down and remove the old container (**1.0**) and launch a the new instance **1.1**?

**OR**

- Should get into the current running container and only update the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal practice using CI/CD tool like Jenkins is as follows:

1) Make a job in Jenkins(ideally a Jenkins pipeline job) that should checkout the code from your SCM repository and then run the defined unit test and isolated integration test on that code.

2) That job then create the image out of your code and properly tag it and store it your required docker repository.

3) The job then should go to your docker host and pull the new docker image, stop the old container and run the new container afterwards.

4) As an optional step you can setup a cron in your host running the docker containers to manage the old orphaned images and containers.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new "1.1" image, stop and remove the old container and launch a new one based on the 1.1 image. This way the new image represents a self-contained application that can be deployed with no changes on any environment (local, testing, production...)